# Change image in imageview onClick

Tags: android, android-imageview, onclicklistener

I want to change the images in image view on `Onclick` function. I have already tried this:

```
bt_audiocapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (checkPermission()) {

                if (bt_audiocapture.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_mic).equals(R.drawable.ic_mic)) {
                    start();
                    bt_audiocapture.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_stop);
                } else if (bt_audiocapture.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_stop).equals(R.drawable.ic_stop)) {
                    stop();
                    bt_audiocapture.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                } else if (bt_audiocapture.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play).equals(R.drawable.ic_play)) {
                    play();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bt_audiocapture.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_mic)` returns a `Drawable` object. You can't compare it to `R.drawable.ic_mic`, which is `integer`. That is something like comparing a `car` to `green color`.

To accomplish your task, make some field like `private int state = 0;`, and some constants like

```
private final STATE_PLAYING = 1;
private final STATE_STOPPED = 2;
private final STATE_NONE = 0;
```

and then:

```
if (state == STATE_NONE) {
    start();
    bt_audiocapture.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_stop);
    state = STATE_PLAYING;
} else if (state == STATE_PLAYING) {
    stop();
    bt_audiocapture.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
    state = STATE_STOPPED;
} else if (state == STOPPED) {
    play();
    state = STATE_PLAYING;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `equals` expressions always return false, I would expect that none of your `if` blocks is executed. Did you debug that code?

I would suggest to keep the state in another variable, e.g. with an `enum`.

Additionally you should use `setImageDrawable` for performance reasons. See the javadoc of `setImageResource`:

> This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup

Comment: hi jayearn ia hve tried using setImageDrawable method .. but its giving me an error

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, its working for me:-

```
 img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    img.setTag(0);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.images);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (Integer.parseInt(img.getTag().toString()) == 0) {
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.cam);
                img.setTag(1);

            } else {
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.images);
                img.setTag(0);

            }
        }
    });
```